# jQuery function called in a .bind click handler is running on document ready

Tags: jquery

I defined a simple function and attached a "click" handler to a link using .bind().

The function is not running on click - rather, it is running on document ready. Not sure why this is happening.

I am using jQuery 1.3.2.

HTML

```
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  leftTurn = function($message){
    alert ($message);        
  };

  $('a').bind('click', leftTurn('hello'));
});
```

The code is also [here in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/UkzXL/)

Comment: +1 for well formed question and jsfiddle link. @gov's answer taught me something too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to use the callback/handler of bind:

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){
    leftTurn();    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UkzXL/1/)

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
 .bind( eventType, [ eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Comment: Yep -- I made this mistake a lot early on working with jQuery. Wrapping a function call inside a function is still a little odd to me.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling the function when you include `()` at the end.  The `.bind()` function expects a reference to the function itself, not the called result.

```
leftTurn = function(){
        alert ('hello');        
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').bind('click', leftTurn);
});
```

Comment: Nice. Works in a simple function with no arguments, but how do you pass an argument to the function? I edited the code in the question and the jsfiddle

Comment: I would probably write it as jyoseph did, but alternatively you can pass data into the handler like so: http://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data