# Function executing on Bind instead of Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Problem: A function I am binding with a click event is firing off on bind.

I've found others with this same problem and found a couple of answers. However, on implementing those solutions, I am still seeing the same issue. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Demo of issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/b35krwfh/16/

Original snippet of code (coffeescript) that was calling the function on bind:

```
$("body").bind "click", deviceCloseView
```

After some online research, I found the below as the recommended fix, but I'm still experiencing the same issue:

```
$("body").bind "click", ->
  deviceCloseView()
```

Update: it was suggested I remove the parenthesis, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue as it isn't executing at all when I do that:

```
$("body").bind "click", ->
  deviceCloseView
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b35krwfh/15/

Some references I used trying to fix this:

[jQuery function called in a .bind click handler is running on document ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473128/jquery-function-called-in-a-bind-click-handler-is-running-on-document-ready)

[Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load)

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce this. `$("body").bind "click", deviceCloseView` works as expected, as in it calls the function on "click".

Comment: Are you sure? I've made a jsfiddle demoing it with that and while deviceOpenView executes. deviceCloseView does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/b35krwfh/12/

Comment: You might want to engage in a little bit of debugging before asking for help, just a couple `console.log` calls (https://jsfiddle.net/ck51y35b/) will show that your code isn't doing what you expect it to. Clicking the image opens it and then immediately closes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deviceOpenView` in your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b35krwfh/12/) does not stop propagation of the click event. As you bind `deviceCloseView` to the `body`, it will get triggered by the same click as well.

You need to change `deviceOpenView` to stop the propagation of the click event to prevent this.

```
deviceOpenView = (event) ->
  event.stopPropagation();
  // ... your other code
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks a lot. Reading up more on propagation now, but that makes a lot of sense. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your event is bubbling. Here is a fixed fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6nk3asfw/

Call preventDefault, stopPropagation, return false, I just did all of them :)

Some code:

```
deviceOpenView = (e) ->
    console.log("open");
    console.dir(e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. I needed to do more reading on propagation.